# Platinum-coated razor blades for making a fuel cell

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment, fuel

My daughter wants to construct a fuel cell for a school project. Budget is tight and platinum as preferred catalyst expensive. I know that Gillette razor blades are coated with platinum. Would there be a way to use old razor blades for making a fuel cell?

Comment: Umm...Looks to me like "Platinum" is used as a marketing/sales tool. See [Gillette's description of their Platinum-Plus Double-Edged Blade](https://gillette.com/en-us/products/razors-trimmers-and-blades/all-razors/platinum-plus-double-edge-blade), which is made from stainless steel.

Comment: I've been in the Gillette factory near London. I can positively confirm they do coat their razor blades with real platinum, tiny amounts however.

Comment: I've also been in their other factory in Berlin. Same story. The amount is very very small. From memory they use less than a kg to coat millions of blades. Been a number of years ago however. At that time the first gen Gillette sensor came out.

Comment: @Kemmer Happen to know *why* they'd put platinum in their razors? Given, it's a minute quantity, but I don't see much point in doing so :/

Comment: Not sure why they did it. Only thing I can think of is to increase corrosion resistance.

Comment: I think polymers like Teflon are put over the Pt , so it may not be very exposed. Pt and Teflon both provide corrosion protection ; bare steel blades are dull after one use due to corrosion , not wear.